# c++ compilation error ambiguous symbol and tlb files

Tags: visual-c++

I searched but didn't see this exact issue answered.  We have code (I am building it, not writing it) that fails to compile intermittently due to ambiguous symbol errors.  This code produces *.tlb files which evidently contain identical symbols.  The developer claims that his code is not the cause of this, but it is the MS build tool.  He wants us to reboot when this error occurs.  I would think he could change something in the code to alleviate this problem.  Can anyone give me some guidance about this?  And if it can be fixed in the code, how would it get done, please?

Compiling...
                 Err_ProjFile: \websvc\AdminWebService\TestNsEndpointInteropClient\TestNsEndpointInteropClient.vcxproj
                  Err_SrcFile: TestNsEndpointInteropClient.cpp
                  Err_LineNum: 31   col: 0
                   Err_Target: ClCompile
                  Err_Message: C2872: 'EndpointTypeEnum_CenterCord' : ambiguous symbol

Below are the files that reference the tlb files.
websvc
   common\lib-proprietary\Aspect.UnifiedIP.Notifications.EndpointClient.tlb
  websvc\AdminWebService\AdminWebService.sln
     websvc\AdminWebService\TestNsEndpointInteropClient\TestNsEndpointInteropClient.vcxproj

websvc\AdminWebService\TestNsEndpointInteropClient\Aspect.UnifiedIP.Notifications.Common.tlb
    websvc\NotificationServer\NotificationServer.sln
   websvc\NotificationServer\NsCommon\NsCommon.csproj

Comment: You'll want to add the exact error outputs you're seeing. And maybe some further details about what you're trying to do.

Comment: The error is in the question above.  Compiling... Err_ProjFile: \websvc\AdminWebService\TestNsEndpointInteropClient\TestNsEndpointInteropClient.vcxproj Err_SrcFile: TestNsEndpointInteropClient.cpp Err_LineNum: 31 col: 0 Err_Target: ClCompile Err_Message: C2872: 'EndpointTypeEnum_CenterCord' : ambiguous symbol

Comment: I am trying to build the code and convince the developer that this is something he can fix.

Comment: It's unclear how rebooting would fix the problem as stated. The error is just saying there is a name conflict. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t57wswcs.aspx.